# Animate background UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation

I have this asset as the background of a view and its assigned to the background using the code described below.

The animation is to get the diagonal rows animate, so they move from left to right when the loading is happening.

Any pointers of how to get this done?

```
var view = UIImageView()
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.image = UIImage(assetIdentifier: "background-view")
view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
view.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
view.clipsToBounds = true
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

return view
```

"background-view" is here
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best would be to have all the images needed ( all the frames ) to create the animated image you want and then put these images in `UIImageView's animationImages` property.

For instance, if you get a loading bar gif `loading_bar.gif`, you can get all the different images in that gif ( c.f. this tutorial among others : http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/preview-extracting-frames-from-animated-gifs ).

Load all the images in your code ( in the assets folder for instance ) and then do something like :

```
func getAnimatedImages -> Array<UIImage>
{
    var animatedImages = Array<UIImage>()
    var allImagesLoaded = false
    var i = 0
    while !allImagesLoaded
    {
        if let image = UIImage(named: "background_" + String(i))
        {
            animatedImages.append(image)
            i++
        }
        else
        {
            allImagesLoaded = true
        }
    }

    return animatedImages
}
```

( if you called your images background_0, background_1, etc... )
and then

```
self.yourBackgroundImageView.animationImages = self.getAnimatedImages
self.yourBackgroundImageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Can we not use some location property and animate it? I wanted to avoid having multiple images

Answer (score 0):

I would use the  method [class func animatedImageNamed(_ name: String, duration duration: NSTimeInterval) -> UIImage?](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/animatedImageNamed:duration:)

From the Apple doc:

> this method would attempt to load images from files with the names ‘image0’, ‘image1’ and so on all the way up to ‘image1024’. All images included in the animated image should share the same size and scale.

If you create an animated image you can assign it to your UIImageView and it will animate automatically.

As for the image creation [@Randy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35755489/440299) had a pretty good idea :)

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating more images so I wanted to use the same image and get the effect.

Comment: You can code the animation. I don't know maybe use a bigger image and move it forward > reset to zero > forward again and so on... Smells a little hacky do : )

Comment: For sure, you can do it with core graphic ... http://www.coreanimator.com/#animatecode

Comment: using that won't I end up creating multiple images? I believe we should just use the same "background-image" and animate it some way and then kinda show the loading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105191/discussion-between-sana-and-mt81).